# What kind of motors do industrial robot have?

Tags: robotic-arm, motor, servomotor

What kind of motors do industrial robots use and how do you control them?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Da Mango, but I'm afraid that questions which are as broad as this are off-topic because answers would need to be too long. As it says in [ask] *If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much*. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so please take a look at [ask], [about] and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for advice on writing a good question.

Answer (score 5):

Most industrial robot have [servo motors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servomotor). This allows you to control velocity, torque and position of motors - the latter usually in some form of closed-loop control system.

I work for Stäubli. Our early robots were actually hydraulic, the UniMate. Next were the PUMA robots which had DC servo motors. The modern RX, TX, TX2, TS, and TS2 arms have 3-phase AC servo motors.